# Business Objects Web Intelligence: Dynamic Input Controls

Tags: business-objects

I have a report with 2 input controls: team leader and employee. Lets say that we have 2 teams:

1. Andy's team: composed of Alice, Bob and Charlie
2. Bert's team: composed of Alfred and Cheryl

At the moment, the input controls show all employees (Alice, Bob, Charlie, Alfred and Cheryl) regardless of which team I choose. If I choose Bert, I'd like to see *just* his 2 employees.

My question is: **how can I change the list of employees in my input control, based on the selection of the team leader input control?**

*Specification*: Business Objects 4, web intelligence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the input controls will show you all the values that have been retrieved from the database for that dimension, regardless of selections made in other report filters and/or input controls.